# Firebase functions - Frontend authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase function i use as a middleware to redirect frontend requests to either static SSR version or the dynamic version of my site.

However I now need to add also logic to change the response if the user is logged in using Firebase Auth. I've seen most examples based on the [secure HTTPS example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) but it seems to depend on us manually adding the Auth header or the "__session" cookie, which might be OK for a backend endpoint but I'm handling frontend requests straight from the user.

Is there some way to check from a function if the user is logged in to Firebase? I don't event need the ID i just need to know if its logged so I can point them to the right destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any mechanism you like to get that auth ID token from the browser/frontend to the function.  Query string, HTTP header, session cookies, it doesn't matter.  You just need to get the token into the function so it can use the Admin SDK to call `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)` (as you can see in the sample code you linked to) in order to see if it's a legitimate user.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Doug, my  problem is that I don't know how to get that token. Where does Firebase store that information on the client? is that accessible inside the function context.

Comment: You have to come up with a way to transmit it during the http request so it can be used by the function. It's not automatic or stored.

Comment: that was the piece of the puzzle i was missing, i thought the __session cookie was saved by default. Thanks